# Reference request: Atiyah-Segal completion on spectrum level

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It seems like the Atiyah Segal completion theorem for the two element group 
$G = \mathbb Z_2$ and one-point space $X=\{ * \}$ with trivial G action yields a statement about the underlying spectra as follows.

Let $KO$ denote the real K-theory spectrum, $RO(G)$ the real character ring of $G$  and $\hat{RO(G)} \cong \mathbb Z \oplus  \hat {\mathbb Z}_2$ its $I_G$-adic completion. 
Let $\hat{KO}_2$ denote the 2-adic completion of the spectrum $KO$, i.e. its homotopy groups look like those of $KO$ completed at 2.

Then $\hat{RO(G)} \otimes K^*(\{ * \}) \cong  \pi_*(KO \vee \hat{KO_2})$ and it seems

$KO \vee \hat{KO_2} \rightarrow map(B\mathbb Z _2, KO)$

is a homotopy equivalence of spectra (inducing the Atiyah Segal completion isomorphism on their homotopy groups).

Does anybody know a reference for this (probably correct) fact? Or a reference to related problems?